# Filter across columns with equal values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'd like to filter a dataframe if at least two columns of the df are equal, but in a dynamic way.
Suppose the following dataframe :

```
data.frame(Var1 = c(1,1,1,2,3,4,4),Var2=c(1,2,6,8,2,5,4),Var3=c(1,3,5,6,7,5,6))
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    1    1
2    1    2    3
3    1    6    5
4    2    8    6
5    3    2    7
6    4    5    5
7    4    4    6
```

I'd like to keep values that are not equal at all, so if at least 2 columns are equal by row, they will be deleted. The final result should be :

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3
2    1    2    3
3    1    6    5
4    2    8    6
5    3    2    7
```

As the number of columns in my dataframe should be incremented, it would be better if it is something dynamic, inspired by the mutate(across()) statement.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(c_across()) > 2)

# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Rowwise: 
   Var1  Var2  Var3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3
2     1     6     5
3     2     8     6
4     3     2     7
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr it can be done as shown below:

```
df |> dplyr::filter_all(dplyr::all_vars(. != dplyr::first(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more updated way to do this in `dplyr` is to use `if_any`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(if_any(Var2:Var3, ~ .x != Var1))
```

---

You can also use `collapse::varying` to test for variation in the data:

```r
df[collapse::varying(t(df)), ]
```